# How can I incorporate the way that SQL Server 2014 displays spatial results into my .NET Application?

Tags: c#, sql-server, spatial

When I query a table that has an SqlGeometry field there's a 'Spatial results' tab that actually draws the spatial data returned.  Is it using some sort of control that I can leverage in a .NET application?  If not, how can I duplicate this functionality?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using a SSRS report within your application?

Comment: I haven't, good idea.  I'll give it a try.

Comment: Its not bad, but in SSMS you can move the map around and zoom in and out.  I'd like to be able to do that as well.

Comment: Here is a starting point if you want to try and make your own control. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29153/SQL-Geometry-Viewer

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything built-in that will do the job.

What you could do is integrate a third-party usercontrol that will do the display.

For instance you could use [GMap.Net](http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/) and display some `GMapPolygon` on a map. Do note you'll have to convert `SqlGeometry`/`SqlGeography` to a list of points, so converting to/from WKT might be required.

Comment: This works best with SqlGeography fields (that have long & lat) it seems.  I need something that will draw SqlGeometry data.